# just getting started using shopify js api and getting an error when trying to run my angular application

Tags: angular, shopify

I'm getting this error in the console.

> __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_shopify_buy___default.a is not a constructor

```
    import Client, {Config} from 'shopify-buy';

    const config = new Config({
      domain: 'something.myshopify.com',
      accessToken: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      appId : x
    });

    const client = new Client(config);
```

Seems to be yelling at "const client = new Client(config);".... But that's what they have in their documentation. Am I doing something wrong? If so, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but from their documentation you can do something like following.

```js
import ShopifyBuy from 'shopify-buy';

const shopClient = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
  apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1403c107adc7e',
  domain: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.myshopify.com',
  appId: '6',
});

export function fetchAllProducts() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    shopClient.fetchAllProducts()
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('shopClient.fetchAllProducts', data);
        resolve(data);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(new Error('Fetching products error!'));
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}
```

Hope this will help.